# Searchview for Json parsed data

Tags: android, json, listview, searchview

I have parsed the data in a listview and is displayed. I have to implement searchview in the displayed data. I have a getmTitle () function that has the title of the list in listview. now if I write in searchview, listview should select the typed title and be displayed.

```
public class ImageListActivity {

private String id;
private String title;
private String url_s;

public ImageListActivity(String id, String title, String url_s) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.url_s = url_s;
}

public String getmId() {
    return id;
}

public String getmTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getmUrl_s() {return url_s;}
}
```

Below is my adapter class:

```
public class AdapterActivity extends ArrayAdapter<ImageListActivity> {



public AdapterActivity(Activity context, ArrayList<ImageListActivity> image) {
    super(context, 0, image);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItemView = convertView;

    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.default_layout, parent, false);
    }


    ImageListActivity currentWord = getItem(position);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.flickr_image);

    try {
        Picasso.get()
                .load(currentWord.getmUrl_s())
                .into(imageView);
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        /* sets image to default image

         */
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_img);

    }

    TextView image_id = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.flickr_id);
    image_id.setText(currentWord.getmId());

    return listItemView;


}


}
```

I don't know what to do in the code below:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search Images");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            techListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            SearchActivity.SearchAsyncTask task = new SearchActivity.SearchAsyncTask();
            task.execute(USGS_REQUEST_URL);
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

        }
    });
```

This is my projects link https://github.com/sivaperumal644/Gallery

Comment: What u need to perform the local search OR service calling search

Comment: local search, I have fetched data from the api and displayed in the app. Now I have a searchbar and I have to implement search  function for the fetched data

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do. First of all implement Filterable in you adapter where you need to implement the logic of filtering your data. Secondly you need to call adapter.getFilter() in your onQueryTextChange() to trigger the filter. Please check this link.

https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/